# Cannot use relative path when using img tag react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, path

I have a img tag that is not loading the image i want when i use a relative src path for my React project.
When I do:

```
//import { ReactComponent } from '*.svg';
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "./firebase.js";
import "./LobbyStyle.css";
import pfp2 from "./images/pfp2.png"

class ImgButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super();
    }

    render(props){
        return (<button style = {{backgroundColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)", borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"}}><img src = {pfp2} onClick = {this.props.onClick}/></button>)
    }
}

class ImgRow extends React.Component {

    render(){
        var iconlist = this.props.images.map(image => 
            <div key = {image} >
                <ImgButton onClick = {this.props.onClick} img = {image}/>
            </div>
        )
        return(
            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                {iconlist}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ImgRow;
```

It displays the following:
[image: pfp2 is the orange doodle on the right]

However when I replace the imported image with a relative path It doesn't load:

```
//import { ReactComponent } from '*.svg';
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "./firebase.js";
import "./LobbyStyle.css";
//import pfp2 from "./images/pfp2.png"

class ImgButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super();
    }

    render(props){
        return (<button style = {{backgroundColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)", borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"}}><img src = {"./images/pfp2.png"} onClick = {this.props.onClick}/></button>)
    }
}

class ImgRow extends React.Component {

    render(){
        var iconlist = this.props.images.map(image => 
            <div key = {image} >
                <ImgButton onClick = {this.props.onClick} img = {image}/>
            </div>
        )
        return(
            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                {iconlist}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ImgRow;
```

[image]

What am i doing wrong? is it necessary to import my images? Here is my file path, as you can see i believe the relative path is correct, since the images folder is in the same folder as my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [bundling](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#bundling).

> Most React apps will have their files “bundled” using tools like Webpack, Rollup or Browserify. **Bundling is the process of following imported files and merging them into a single file: a “bundle”. This bundle can then be included on a webpage to load an entire app at once.**

When this bundling of your react app occurs all the imported assets, such as your images, are as the word implies bundled together. A relative image path means nothing because that path doesn't exist in the context of the bundled code and assets that are loaded as your react app on the webpage.

Importing the image is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use require for inline image src

```
<img src = {require('./images/pfp2.png')} onClick = {this.props.onClick}/>
```